Nginx with Varnish load balancer redirecting all traffic to one of the two backend servers
We are using varnish 5.2.1 with nginx 1.23.1 in the front for SSL. We want to use varnish to cache static stuff like images/css etc and also as a load balancer. It seems like all of the traffic ends up on one of the servers and the other backend server is idle. Here is our default.vcl
vcl 4.0;

import std;
import directors;
import cookie;
import header;

backend server1 {
  .host = "slave1.example.com:8080";
  .probe = {
                .url = "/";
                .interval = 5s;
                .timeout = 5s;
                .window = 5;
                .threshold = 3;
  }
}

backend server2 {
  .host = "slave2.example.com:8080";
  .probe = {
                .url = "/";
                .interval = 5s;
                .timeout = 5s;
                .window = 5;
                .threshold = 3;
  }
}


sub vcl_init {
    new cluster = directors.hash();
    cluster.add_backend(server1, 1);
    cluster.add_backend(server2, 1);
}

sub vcl_recv {
    # send all traffic to the bar director:
    set req.backend_hint = cluster.backend(client.ip);
}


The nginx configuration is like so:
server {

       listen         80;
       server_name    www.example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:6081;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port 443;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }

}


We are testing using a VPN to simulate multiple IP addresses. If we go to varnish 6081 port directly then the traffic is distributed correctly. However, if we go through nginx first, all of the traffic ends up on one the first server. I am guessing this is has something to do with 'client.ip' not getting passed correctly to varnish.
SOLUTION: (The following is working ).
set req.backend_hint = cluster.backend(req.http.X-Real-IP);


@Thijs Feryn can you please take a look? Thanks

" It seems like all of the traffic ends up on one of the servers and the other backend server is idle." How are you determining that? Can you update your question to include a reproducible test? Depending on how you're testing things, the caching may be skewing your results.

@PrashantSaraswat I think Larsks explanation is spot on, and I can't really add anything to it. Read it, analyze it, learn from it. It has all the answers your need in terms of backend distribution & fallback.

thanks, I am watching the backend servers' tomcat access logs. One of the access logs keep rolling. The other one doesn't. We get about ~50K unique visitors per day. I also tested manually by changing ip address using a VPN and deleting cookies. These requests also always end up on the same server.

As I indicated in a comment, I'm suspicious that the behavior you're seeing is an artifact of how you're testing things. Barring more information in your question, here's my analysis of what's going on.

In order to take a closer look at things, I set up a test environment with Docker compose, using a Varnish frontend and two simple backends. The associated compose.yaml looks like this:
services:
  backend1:
    image: docker.io/traefik/whoami
    hostname: backend1
    command:
    - -verbose
  backend2:
    image: docker.io/traefik/whoami
    hostname: backend2
    command:
    - -verbose
  frontend:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Containerfile
    volumes:
    - ./varnish:/etc/varnish/
    ports:
    - 127.0.0.1:8080:80

The backends are running whoami, a trivial http server that returns information about the request, including the hostname on which the service is running.
The Containerfile for the frontend looks like this:
FROM fedora:40

RUN yum -y install varnish varnish-modules
CMD ["varnishd", "-F", "-f", "/etc/varnish/default.vcl"]

And the varnish configuration is pretty much identical to what you've posted, but the hostnames have been changed to match the compose configuration:
vcl 4.0;

import std;
import directors;
import cookie;
import header;

backend server1 {
        .host = "backend1:80";
        .probe = {
                .url = "/";
                .interval = 5s;
                .timeout = 5s;
                .window = 5;
                .threshold = 3;
        }
}

backend server2 {
        .host = "backend2:80";
        .probe = {
                .url = "/";
                .interval = 5s;
                .timeout = 5s;
                .window = 5;
                .threshold = 3;
        }
}


sub vcl_init {
        new cluster1 = directors.hash();
        cluster1.add_backend(server1, 1);
        cluster1.add_backend(server2, 1);
}


sub vcl_recv {
        if(req.url ~ "^/solr"){
                return(synth(404,""));
        }


        if ( (req.url ~ "images.html" && req.url !~ "nocache") || (req.url ~ "\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|css|js)$") ) {
                unset req.http.cookie;
        }

        cookie.parse(req.http.cookie);
        if (cookie.get("JSESSIONID")) {
                set req.http.sticky = cookie.get("JSESSIONID");
        } else {
                set req.http.sticky = std.random(1, 100);
        }

        set req.backend_hint = cluster1.backend(req.http.sticky);
}


sub vcl_deliver {
        if (req.http.sticky) {
                header.append(resp.http.Set-Cookie,"sticky=bar" + req.http.sticky + ";   Expires=" + cookie.format_rfc1123(now, 60m));
        }
}

If I make several requests to the same URL, it looks like the requests are all being handled by the same server. Running this script:
for i in {1..100}; do
  curl -sf localhost:8080/example | grep -i hostname
done | sort | uniq -c

Results in:
100 Hostname: backend2

But if we watch the logs for the backend servers while running that script, we only see a single request for /example:
$ docker compose logs backend2 | grep /example
backend2-1  | 2024/07/29 00:20:24 172.28.0.2:53360 - - [29/Jul/2024:00:20:24 +0000] "GET /example HTTP/1.1" - -

That's because Varnish only needed to contact a backend for the first request; all subsequent requests were handled by the Varnish cache.
On the other hand, if we repeat the test but use a unique url for each request:
for i in {1..100}; do
  curl -sf localhost:8080/example/${RANDOM} | grep -i hostname
done | sort | uniq -c

We see that the requests are split roughly 50/50 between the two backends:
42 Hostname: backend1
58 Hostname: backend2

In this case, because each request was for a previously unseen URL, Varnish had to contact a backend for every request.


Also, is there a way to configure a fallback as well, so that if one of the backend server goes down, the other one will pick up traffic?

You already have that behavior. Once a backend has been declared "sick", requests that would normally be serviced by that backend will instead be hosted by the other backend.
Your backend configuration determines how quickly Varnish recognizes that a backend is unavailable. With an interval of 5s and a threshold of 3, it will take Varnish at least 15 seconds to recognize that a backend is unhealthy. If a backend is dropping packets instead of rejecting them, a request won't fail until the timeout has expired.
Using your vcl, we can demonstrate this by taking down one of the backends and then repeating our randomized url test. First, we take down backend1:
docker compose down backend1

Then we wait for backend1 to be marked unhealthy by Varnish; we can check the backend health using the varnishadm backend.list command. Once the backend is unhealthy:
Backend name    Admin      Probe    Health     Last change
boot.server1    probe      0/5      sick       Mon, 29 Jul 2024 00:52:32 GMT
boot.server2    probe      5/5      healthy    Mon, 29 Jul 2024 00:52:32 GMT
boot.cluster1   healthy    0/0      healthy    Mon, 29 Jul 2024 00:58:54 GMT

If we repeat our earlier test:
for i in {1..100}; do
  curl -sf localhost:8080/example/${RANDOM} | grep -i hostname
done | sort | uniq -c

We will see that all of the requests are handled by backend2:
100 Hostname: backend2


You can find the files I used to create the test environment here.

Many thanks for analyzing and spending so much time on it. I will create a similar test at my end and get back with results.
